# Why jQuery trigger or triggerHandler doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

Here is my code :

```
<html>
<head>
     <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

     <script type='text/javascript'>
     window.onload=function(){

     var e = jQuery.Event( "click" );
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#rrx").triggerHandler(e);
     $("#rrx").trigger("click");

    }  

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <a href="http://google.com" id="rrx" > gooooooog </a>

</body>
</html>
```

After page load I should be redirected to http://google.com but this is not happening!

Comment: use native DOM click method: `window.onload = function () {
    $("#rrx")[0].click();
}`  http://jsfiddle.net/3F9aQ/show/

Comment: You are right your fiddle works fine but do you know what is wrong with my code !? According to jQuery reference I coded it right! http://api.jquery.com/trigger/#trigger-eventType-extraParameters

Comment: Why are you doing `e.preventDefault();`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat You can get rid it it but it doesn't help. Still click is not executed

Comment: Because jQuery doesn't fire native click method on anchor tag, your code was correct but just doesn't fire native click behaviour

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks! your comments could be the answer as well!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call native click method on anchor tag, jQuery trigger method cannot do it, so you need:

```
window.onload = function () { $("#rrx")[0].click(); }
```

Which is the same as:

```
window.onload = function () { document.getElementById('rrx').click(); }
```