# MouseEvent undefined in .NET WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, javascript, internet-explorer, browser, webbrowser-control

Why this is happening and how to fix this issue ?

Here is what's happening.
A error is thrown by WebBrowser control which says :
An error has occureed in the script in this page.
Error: 'MouseEvent is undefined'

```
SetFeatureBrowserFeature("FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", 9999);
//This forces my WebBrowser control to use IE9+ which in my case it's using IE 10

        var anyScripts = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("script");

        if (anyScripts == null || anyScripts.Count == 0) webBrowser1.Document.Body.AppendChild(webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script"));

        object f = webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new[] {
                        @"
function simulateClick() {
  var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
    'view': window,
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': true
  });
  var cb = document.getElementById('rrx'); 
  var canceled = !cb.dispatchEvent(event);
  if (canceled) {
    // A handler called preventDefault.
    alert('canceled');
  } else {
    // None of the handlers called preventDefault.
    alert('not canceled');
  }
}; simulateClick();"
                    });
```

Comment: What is happening? what's the problem, exactly? :)

Comment: @Noseratio Thanks for pointing out! I have edited question and added more detail!

Comment: I think I have an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21899183/1768303).